# Persisting the state of Redux store when page reloads

Tags: angular, redux, persistence

I'm using Redux in my angular application with the NgReduxModule (https://github.com/angular-redux/store), and this is working fine. 
However, when I reload the webpage, the store is emptied. I know that this is how it should work. I've looked at methods of persisting the data of the store. One solution is the following: https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist

However, I do not understand how this is supposed to work. I configure my store like this:

```
  constructor(ngRedux: NgRedux<SessionState>, private devTools: DevToolsExtension) {
    let enhancers = [ devTools.enhancer() ];
    ngRedux.configureStore(
      sessionStateReducer,
      INITIAL_STATE, [], enhancers);
  }
```

Where am I supposed to add the persistor, or can I not use this with NgReduxModule? Before I configured my store like this:

```
StoreModule.provideStore(
      compose(
        localStorageSync({keys: ['sessionState'], rehydrate: true}),
        combineReducers
      )({sessionState})
    )
```

This wouldn't persist the store either.. Does anybody have a working example for this?

Comment: Did you solve this problem finally?

Comment: I solved this problem by configuring the store with an object read from local storage (if available). If it's not available, I use an INITIAL_STATE constant. I'm not sure if this is the optimal way of doing it, but it works for me.